# Eloquent not returning same results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm having a weird issue with Eloquent. One environment requires quotes to be wrapped around the id, while the other requires no quotes.

In my local environment using Homestead the following works:

```
$model = App\Model::where('field', 123)->get();
```

On production using a very similar setup (LEMP stack - same php version):

```
$model = App\Model::where('field', '123')->get();
```

If I reverse these then neither will return anything. The database is exactly the same, I did a direct sync between the two just to be sure. I'm not sure what could be causing this difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Things to check: Are you sure that the datatype of the id column is the same between the two databases (I know you said "The database is exactly the same" but it doesn't hurt to double check). Also turn on MySQL query logging and see what the two SELECT statements look like.

Comment: Yeah, I just double checked it. The same SELECT works on both servers. My only workaround is to check the environment and return the model that works in that specific one. Of course, this is not really ideal.

Comment: Have you tried using `find` instead? and let me know if it returns something good. 
`$model = App\Model::find($id);`

Comment: Im actually not using "id" I'm looking for a specific column "channel_id" which is an integer, and not primary key.

Comment: Do you have different version of MySQL on your server and Homestead?

Comment: Had the same issue in a work project, we just needed to update the mysql driver on the staging/production environment and everything was fine again.